# Allow only one instance of route at one time

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

I have a controller:

```
 @GetMapping("/startRoute")
    @ApiOperation(value = "startDRoute",
           
            response = ResponseEntity.class)
    public ResponseEntity<BaseResponse<Boolean>> startRoute() {

        logger.info("ReconciliationController - startDaily called");

        ReconciliationBatchRequest reconciliationBatchRequest = new ReconciliationBatchRequest();

        reconciliationBatchRequest.setDocumentTypeOfJob(0L);//hardcoded change

        producerTemplate
                .asyncSendBody(DOCUMENT_RECONCILIATION_ROUTE_START,
                         reconciliationBatchRequest);

        logger.info("ReconciliationController - startDaily ended");

        return ResponseEntity.ok(new BaseResponse<>(true));
    }
```

it starts the camel route :

```
    @Override
    public void configure() {

        logger.info("DocumentReconciliationRoute configure started");

        onException(Exception.class)
                .process(reconciliationExceptionProcessor)
//                .handled(true).maximumRedeliveries(3).redeliveryDelay(0)
        ;

        from("direct:DocumentReconciliationRoute.start")
                .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, DOCUMENT_RECONCILIATION_ROUTE, "Daily camel route started")
                .routeId("reconciliationCamelRoute")
                .process(createFTPExpressionProcessor)
                .to(GET_FILE_FROM_SFTP)
                .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, DOCUMENT_RECONCILIATION_ROUTE, "Daily camel route ended")
//                .end()
```

Beause it comes from controller async, it can be called multiple times. But i dont want this. It should not work if there is one running route.

I created this to stop if there is active route:

```
@GetMapping("/stop")
@ApiOperation(value = "stop",
        notes = "For stopping reconciliation",
        response = ResponseEntity.class)
public ResponseEntity<String> stop() throws Exception {

    logger.info("ReconciliationController - stop called");

    camelContext.stopRoute("reconciliationCamelRoute");

    logger.info("ReconciliationController - stop ended");

    return ResponseEntity.ok("ok");
}
```

but if there is runnin route, this does not stop. It waits :

```
Starting to graceful shutdown 1 routes (timeout 300 seconds)
```

How can I make only one instance is working even multiple people calls that controller endpoind?

I tried this:

```
 boolean isRouteStarted =
((org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport)route).isStarted();
```

but is this safe?